# Remove leading 0 from Contact Form 7 [tel] mail-tag output

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to find a way to remove leading 0 from Contact Form 7 `[tel]` mail-tag output.

Most of the people in the UK put leading 0 before main number. As a result, if someone type 012345678 in phone input, CF7 `[tel]` mail-tag used in creation of the CF7 mail will display 012345678 (even, if `<input type="">` is `"tel"`, not `"number"`). I need to find a way to remove leading 0 and make `[tel]` mail-tag display only 12345678.

I need it to make CF7 send mail to 44`[tel]`@my-mail-to-sms-provider.com, so my mail will transform to SMS to the client, that submitted the form. When `[tel]` contains 0 it don't work, because of limitations of mail to sms provider.

If anyone has an idea how to do it without messing with CF7 files, I would be very grateful for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it myself. If someone has a similar problem, here is my code:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'save_application_form', 10, 1 );
function save_application_form($array){
$array["your_field_name"] = ltrim($array["your_field_name"], '0');
return $array;
}
```